# Using $ref for jsonschema in Abao

Tags: jsonschema, raml

Can someone help with schemas refs in abao? How to use --schemas option? Here is simple gist https://gist.github.com/SeanSilke/e5a2f7673ad4aa2aa43ba800c9aec31b

I try to run "abao api.raml --schemas fref.json" but got error " Missing/unresolved JSON schema $refs (fref.json) in schema".

By the way the server is mocked by osprey-mock-service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add id field to your JSON schemas.

For run use: `abao api.raml --server http://localhost:3000 --schemas=./*.json`

Example files:

**api.raml**

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: simple API
baseUri: http://localhost:3000

/song:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            schema: !include schema.json
            example: |
              {
                "songId": "e29b",
                "songTitle": "The song",
                "albumId": "18310"
              }
```

**fref.json**

```
{
  "id": "fref.json",
  "type": "string"
}
```

**schema.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "id": "schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties":{
    "songId": {"$ref": "fref.json"}
  },
  "required": ["songId", "albumId", "songTitle"]
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! It works! Somehow the adding if id's was absolutely not obvious for me.